# S3 Bucket policy and Cognito AWS connection for web and mobile app (rails and ionic)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, ionic-framework, amazon-cognito

I'm trying to use Cognito AWS to create an unauthenticated user connection whenever one of our Users logs into our app (web or mobile). That way I can create a secure S3 bucket policy for registered users.

I'm able to post successfully to Amazon, running this code in the browser.

```
AWS.config.region = 'us-east-1';

AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
    IdentityPoolId: "<%= ENV['AWS_IDENTITY_POOL_ID'] %>",
});

AWS.config.credentials.get(function(){
  aws_client = new AWS.CognitoSync();
});
```

I then expect to be able to access an asset in my S3 bucket (using its url), which has a policy based on my IdentityPool.

The url is simply a link in the markup, not accessed with javascript. What am I missing? When I go to the url from the app, AWS serves up an access denied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you signing the S3 URL from the credentials you get from Cognito? You can sign the S3 URL using any AWS credentials. Take a look at the [getSignedURL](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#getSignedUrl-property) method available in S3.

Also if all you want is to get temporary credentials and access S3 based on the policies of those credentials, you don't need Cognito Sync. Getting credentials from Congito Identity should be enough. [Cognito Sync](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/devguide/sync/) can be used to store and sync data across devices. You don't need to maintain your own S3 resources and worry about synchronization logic if you use Sync service.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks [Chetan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3204480/chetan-mehta), I managed to get things working using getSignedUrl.

For anyone wondering, this is what I did:

Using the Javascript AWS SDK for mobile app:

```
AWS.config.region = 'us-east-1';
AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({ IdentityPoolId: "Our Identity Pool Id, found in Cognito menu" })
var s3 = new AWS.S3()
var params = {Bucket: 'bucket_name', Key: 'file_name'}
var url = s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', params)
```

And on the web app, I can use the slick Ruby aws sdk to write a simple method:

```
# In initializers, as aws.rb
Aws.config.update({
  region: 'us-west-2',
  credentials: Aws::Credentials.new(
  ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
  ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
  )
})

# In the Upload model, or wherever you store image data
def aws_url
  @presigner = Aws::S3::Presigner.new
  @presigner.presigned_url(
    :get_object,
    bucket: ENV['S3_BUCKET'],
    key: file_name,
    expires_in: 1.day.to_i
  ).to_s
end
```

And finally, the S3 bucket policy that allows for both the mobile and web apps to have secure access.

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Id": "http resource policy example",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": "s3:GetObject",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::S3_Bucket_Name/IdentityPoolId"
    }
  ]
}
```